# How to set date axis ticks and labels for all bars?

Tags: r, echarts4r

The problem I have is that I can't find a solution to let me set the x-axis ticks and labels I want for a bar chart with dates on the x-axis.

I am using the echarts4r package to plot a bar plot. By default the x-axis labels are auto populated. Can I set the date labels and ticks so that they are shown for all the bars?

(I have tried a hacky work-around of converting the dates to categories but this creates problems because I want to mark additional lines at different dates than the bars are for which I can't if using categories.)

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(echarts4r)

df <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date(c(paste0(2010:2020, "-06-30"))),
  value = 1:11
)

df |> 
  e_charts(date) |> 
  e_bar(value, name = "value") |>
  e_x_axis(
    axisLabel = list(
      formatter = '{yyyy}-{MM}'
    )
  )
```

This marks ticks and labels at '2012-01', '2014-01', '2016-01', '2018-01', '2020-01'.
But I want tick and labels next to all 11 bars.

From the apache docs there are `xAxis.axisTick.interval` and `xAxis.axisLabel.interval` settings but not when the axis is time.

It might be possible with a more complicated `formatter callback` function but I couldn't get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option which following the example in the [docs](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.maxInterval) uses `maxInterval` to make sure that the gap between axis labels is less than or equal to one year (But don't ask me why we have to multiply by 1000. Perhaps milliseconds?). Additionally I used `min` and `max` to add labels at the lower and upper end.

```r
library(echarts4r)

df <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date(c(paste0(2010:2020, "-06-30"))),
  value = 1:11
)

df |>
  e_charts(date) |>
  e_bar(value, name = "value") |>
  e_x_axis(
    axisLabel = list(
      formatter = "{yyyy}-{MM}"
    ),
    min = "2010-01-01",
    max = "2021-01-01",
    maxInterval = 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000 * 366
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this does not give the labels I want which was the dates for each bar.

Comment: I see. Thought you want just a label for each bar. After another round of google research and screening the docs my reading is that (as of the moment) there is no option to set the tick positions manually. ):